# Excel VBA compose email for multiple To's, CC's and BCC's

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to create a single email that sends to multiple people.
Right now I have email addresses in one column and checkboxes for "Send To", "CC" or "BCC" to the right.

```
Emails address: B3 - B13 (this list will expand, i may end up using lastrow)

"True/False" To: D3- D13

"True/False" CC: F3- F13

"True/False" BCC: H3- H13

Send if TRUE, skip if FALSE.
```

I'm sure this is simple & around already but I have looked and I am stuck.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Is there part of your code that isn't working?  If so, paste your code into the question, tell us where you are having the problem, and we can possibly assist.  But without any clues as to what your issue is, there would be a **very** small chance of us guessing an answer that would help.

Comment: In addition to showing what you've tried, *how* are you trying to send an email? With Outlook? Gmail? Hotmail? Yahoo? Lotus Notes? ...please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a macro which should do what you want, of course adapt it to suit your specific needs as the question was quite vague...

See the comments for explanation.

```
Sub sendEmail()

' Set up outlook objects for emailing

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

' Body text for the email
Dim strbody As String
strbody = "This text in the body of your email"

' Strings to contain the email addresses
Dim sendTo As String
sendTo = ""
Dim sendCC As String
sendCC = ""
Dim sendBCC As String
sendBCC = ""

' The cell containing the email address (loop variable)
Dim emailCell As Range

With ActiveSheet

    ' Cycle through email addresses, from B3 to one before next blank cell in column
    For Each emailCell In .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown))

        ' Check each TRUE/FALSE column in same row, add email addresses accordingly

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "D").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendTo = sendTo & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "F").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendCC = sendCC & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

        If .Cells(emailCell.Row, "H").Text = "TRUE" Then

            sendBCC = sendBCC & "; " & emailCell.Text

        End If

    Next emailCell

End With

' Generate email in outlook objects defined above
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = sendTo
    .CC = sendCC
    .BCC = sendBCC
    .Subject = "Subject Message Here"
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Display 
    ' If you don't want to display the email before sending it, 
    ' simply use .Send instead of .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```